# Does foot size correlate to penis size?

Tags: physiology

I've heard that foot size is linked to the size of a man's penis.

Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Does this mean for people of the same height but different foot size, or just for someone who's 6ft against 5 ft? Taller people are likely to have bigger body parts in general (I'd guess but not offering evidence here), but a specific correlation to shoe size seems less likely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article on [human penis size](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Human_penis_size&oldid=434279337#Penis_size_and_size_of_other_body_parts):

> There is evidence both for and against
> a link between penis size and the size
> of other body parts. One study found a
> weak correlation between the size of
> the stretched penis and foot size and
> height. Another investigation failed
> to find any evidence for a link
> between shoe size and stretched penis
> size.
>
> A potential explanation for a link is
> that the development of the penis in
> an embryo is controlled by some of the
> same Hox genes (in particular HOXA13
> and HOXD13) as those that control the
> development of the limbs. Mutations of
> some Hox genes that control the growth
> of limbs cause malformed genitalia
> (Hand-Foot-Genital Syndrome).

The paper Wikipedia cites for a positive correlation is [this one](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00849563). But the abstract of that paper has some key points which differ slightly from what's mentioned on Wikipedia. Mainly,

> Penile length was found to be
> statistically related to both body
> height and foot length, but with **weak
> correlation coefficients**

and,

> Height and foot size would **not serve**
> as practical estimators of penis
> length.

Comment: in other words there's in theory something there but in reality it doesn't work out?

Comment: @jwenting: looks like that

Comment: Yes, if this were supposed to be true *every time*, it would only need one exception to disprove the rule. I give you *the* exception: the most "gifted" man alive wears size 10.5 ([LINK](http://weirdnews.about.com/od/lovesexandmarriage/a/John-Falcon-Biggest-Penis_3.htm)).

Comment: @Hendy: Big feet ==> big penis does not mean little feet ==> little penis; so that is not an exception :)

Comment: @BlueRaja: What? It's simple... "if P (big feet), then Q (big penis)." Again, if this is supposed to be true *every* time, then showing one instance "if P, then ~Q," means the first argument is negated. P is acting as a predictor. If it P causes both Q and ~Q... it is not causal.

Comment: @Hendy: You didn't show an instance of "if P then ~Q," you showed an instance where "if ~P then Q"

Comment: @BlueRaja: Doh! You are correct, sir -- good eye and thanks for sharpening my thoughts!

Comment: [From that paper:](https://sci-hubtw.hkvisa.net/10.1007/BF00849563) "Foot length and body height (Table 1) were moderately correlated (r = 0.66; p < .10-6). Penis length had a statistically significant relationship to height, although the correlation was relatively weak (r = 0.26; P < 0.05). The relationship between penis length and foot length was also statistically significant, with a similar correlation of r -- 0.27 (p < 0.02)."  Totally looks to me like bigger people have bigger body parts.  An N of 63 seems pretty low for this.